# Robot Framework Language Server Extension automatically opening CANoe application

Tags: visual-studio-code, robotframework, canoe

I use Visual Studio Code with Robot Framework and Python for test purposes. I also use CANoe application as a simulator.
I installed the Robot Framework Language Server and for some reason when I open VSCode or even just click on it CANoe automatically opens, I know that the extension is causing this because if I disable the extension the application stops to automatically open.
Do you already had any similar behavior with Robot Framework Language Server and any other process? If yes, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 different LSP implementations for robot framework. This answer relates mainly to the one Robocorp maintains.

That particular implementation of lsp works by executing each  `LIBRARY` settings section in python interpreter and executing the actual library's constructor to get the data it needs for auto completion / typing / whatnot. If the python library makes any connection to com API thats associated with CANoe during execution of the constructor, it will trigger actual CANoe application to start - even if that's not mandatory at this point but that's how COM works.

I'm quite there are ways to hack around the issue but essentially, the easiest way to fix this is to;

1. Fix the library that provides your keywords that interact with CANoe and/or ecutest or similar that requires CANoe to be running.
2. Try switching to https://github.com/d-biehl/robotcode within vsc to provide you autocomplete and the rest ..
3. If you where using robotcode lsp,  see first suggestion.